# What is this "failed to authenticate" error when starting pgpool?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pgpool

I have configured two EC2 instances, one running postgres, and one running pgpool in hopes of leveraging pgpools connection pooling capabilities.

As part of my config for pgpool, I set the auth-method in both my `pg_hba.conf` and my `pool_hba.conf` to `md5` as well as setting `enable_pool_hba = true` and setting up my `pool_passwd` file in the designated `username:password` format.

for example, my pg_hba.conf and pool_hba.conf have an entry that looks like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
  host  all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

When I start the pgpool service, it responds that it started successfully but then I see a "failed to authenticate" error. See output below:

```
systemd[1]: Started pgpool-II.
pgpool[4234]: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:9999
pgpool[4234]: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::9999
pgpool[4234]: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 3.4.3
pgpool[4234]: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0
pgpool[4234]:
pgpool[4234]: ERROR:  failed to authenticate
pgpool[4234]: DETAIL:  invalid authentication message response type, Expecting 'R' and received 'E'
```

I looked in the logs and didn't see any further information and it looks like everything is up and working and I am able to connect everywhere I need to successfully.

I am wondering if anyone has any insight into this authentication error, what is causing it and where I can find more information about what, if anything is going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what exactly is the cause, but [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html) tells me that the software tried to connect to a PostgreSQL server and got an error response instead of an authentication response. Perhaps the PostgreSQL log file knows more.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for pointing me in this direction. May prove to be useful... I will look into it. Thanks!